# Error while posting to feed: "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I'm getting error while posting a feed on my facebook from url:

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

I'm using

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?name=hello&message=hello_from_url&access_token=access_token`

as my URL. I'm creating a rails app for which I need scope parameter so that I can post on my timeline from rails app but I'm unable to find out the exact solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is that adding `scope` parameter to this posting URL is useless, permissions are set on first use of app depending on the permissions definded in the `scope` on auth dialog.

Your application needs `publish_actions` permission to post feed. And if you add this permission to config you have to authenticate to your app again to accept new permissions.

Use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to check if everything is fine with this. Select your application from dropdown in the top right corner, change method to <kbd>POST</kbd> and paste `me/feed?name=hello&message=hello_from_url`. Then run it and check if you have this exception or not. Click <kbd>Get Access Token</kbd> to check permissions you granted your app.

And BTW, you can use [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) to post feed, if you're not using it:

```
me = FbGraph::User.me(access_token)
 me.feed!(
    :message => '',
    :link => '',
    :name => '',
    :description => ''
  )
```

Comment: My omniauth config file look like this:                         Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], {:scope => "offline_access,read_stream ,manage_pages, publish_stream, publish_actions"}
end                                                                  but still no success.

Comment: @BrahamShakti OmniAuth is for authorization only. You need something more to use Facebook Graph API, like `fb_graph mentioned by me above. [Here](http://superp.tumblr.com/post/4109090091/publish-stream-in-facebook-twitter-with-omniauth) is an example.

Comment: I just wanted to know how do i post feed from url. I am aware of omniauth and what konrad is telling, i already have tried, please click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642142/how-do-i-solve-fbgraphunauthorized-oauthexception-200-the-user-hasnt-a) for reference

Comment: @BrahamShakti First thing is that adding `scope` parameter to this posting URL is useless, permissions are set on first use of app.

Have you authenticated to the app again after adding `publish_actions` to config? Use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to check if everything is fine with this. Select your application from dropdown in the top right corner, change method to POST and paste `me/feed?name=hello&message=hello_from_url`. Then run it and check if you have this exception or not. Click `Get Access Token` to check permissions you granted your app.

Comment: Thank you Konrad that really helps me. It solves my problem. I am really thankful to you.

Comment: @BrahamShakti Great. I have updated my answer to provide info from my last comment. If this answer helps you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was also facing the same problem. Now I got what i want.

Comment: @KonradGadzina, thanks for the answer, I got it working with the help of this :)