# How to set up my Facebook app to allow user wall posts?

Tags: ruby, facebook-apps, koala-gem

I'm trying to post a Facebook wall post from my Ruby script (I'm using `koala` gem). I was able to successfully login to Facebook and get my user token.

However, it won't allow to do a wall post because my Facebook app is not set in a way with necessary permissions.

So what is the option that I could setup in my Facebook app to allow user wall posts ?

I have looked through my Facebook app options and I couldn't find a place for that, and also searching the web didn't help much.

Comment: which permissions have you setup?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, thanks for the comment, actually I cannnot find any option my app developer dash board in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<my app id>/dashboard/

Comment: I meant you have had declated permisstion in your application rails or ruby. when you have gotten a oauth key. for example to make a post you must have `publish_actions` permission: see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart#

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, got it working with the following SO answer, I updated my answer for future reference, thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while posting to feed: "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684434/error-while-posting-to-feed-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to my question and got it working,

Please read the answer to the following question

[Error while posting to feed: "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684434/error-while-posting-to-feed-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perf)

:)